# angularjs code coverage using blackbox testing (running the functional automation test scripts written in protractor) and without unit testing

Tags: angularjs, code-coverage

My requirement is, I should not do the unit testing to know the code coverage of angularjs code. simply to say, when I do black-box testing, I should get the code coverage report of angular js code.

we have automation test scripts for functional testing written in protractor.
Now, when I run these automation test scripts, code coverage report should be generated.

We have NCover tool. But we should use the tool other than this.

I am searching for this but unable to find the exact answer as I am new to protractor and other tools like karma/istanbul/grunt etc.

Please help me on this how I can do this and the setup to do. It will be very helpful to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Basically, when you do Black-Box-Testing you don't see code and can't say anything on code coverage.
Do you mean end-to-end functional testing? And when doing that having monitor, which reports back your code coveragen and the untouched lines of code?

Comment: Thanks for your time. it is like e2e only, but we do some feature wise testing, so the developers know all the methods related to that feature, and when we do the full functional testing for that feature, then we want to know how much % of lines code is executed and missed in the methods related to that particular feature. This is our idea.